# Histogram returning inf values

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram of some data, the data looks quite ok for me.

However the histogram is not being showed, and it is returning `inf` values. I do not get to understand why.

Here is what I am doing:

A sample of my data to plot:

```
>>>y[0:20]
array([  9.03061197,  11.18613147,  10.20833309,  10.52459041,
        12.35042774,  10.94318214,  11.47863285,  11.03543313,
        11.51063833,  11.40573821,  10.91732319,  11.2765148 ,
        11.73077009,  10.19453873,  10.7591238 ,   9.77956991,
         9.7284345 ,  11.8031496 ,  11.11313849,   9.46416353])
```

Then I am using `matplotlib hist`:

```
>>> matplotlib.pyplot.hist(y,50)
(array([-1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]), array([ nan,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,
        inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,
        inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,
        inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,
        inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf]), <a list of 50 Patch objects>)
```

I do not understand what is going on.

I thought I did understand the hist function.

I have used many different bins, but it is not working.

I have also tried to plot the array `y` just using the normal plot:

```
>>>plot(y)
```

[image]

I would appreciate any comment or suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have some irrational number in your `y` array like `nan` or `inf`.
You didn't post all of the values, so you have to check yourself.

you can also do this by:

`pylab.isnan(y).any()`
and
`pylab.isinf(y).any()`

Good luck

Comment: and what does isinf give?

Comment: You are right `>>> pylab.isinf(y).any()
True` I thought nan has the same meaning as inf. However I am ploting all the values using `plot(y)` and i do not see any inf, why?

Comment: because its too large ;-). No really, inf values are just skipped in the plot. You can probably see them as a gap in the graph